# read message from queue/topic in mule

Tags: jms, mule, activemq-classic

I want to implement a consumer kind behaviour using Mule, ActiveMQ which can read JMS messages....there is some third party queue/topic. need to subscribe to them and start listening. How can I achieve that in mule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instructions in [this blog post](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-school-jms-tutorial/) to get a working connector. If you are using JMS1.1 you don't even need to specify queue or topic, they will behave the same. If you are using 1.0b, please make sure you specify the correct type.

Then, instead of using an outbound endpoint use an inbound endpoint:

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint topic="myTopic" connector-ref="Active_MQ" />
```

I do, however, recommend to use [Anypoint Studio](http://www.mulesoft.com/platform/mule-studio), that will provide you a very simple interface for this kind of configurations.

Comment: Hi Victor....thanks for your reply...I saw that blog but in that blog its only adding queue and publishing message to that queue...I didnt see the part where its consuming.

Comment: How can we print the message or check if its listening to that queue? Cause when I am going in "view cosnumers" there is nothing.

Comment: If you are running on a standalone Mule you'll find logs in the logs directory with the name-of-your-app.log.
To print the message arrived just use a <logger level="ERROR"/> right after your inbound-endpoint.

Comment: Great! please accept the asnwer if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

To read a message from activemq queue ot topic, can simply put in your flow for example:

```
<flow name="insert-operation" doc:name="insert-operation" doc:description="">       
    <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="Active_MQ" exchange-pattern="request-response" queue="insert-jms" doc:name="JMS">
        <idempotent-redelivery-policy idExpression="#[message.inboundProperties['JMSMessageID']]" />
        <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" />
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
...
</flow>
```

Comment: what would be the message.inboundProperties['JMSMessageID']?

Comment: The JMSMessageID is a String value that uniquely identifies a message in the queue or topic. In this example, transactions are used, it may not be relevant to your request.

Comment: You can used a flow simple, for example: <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="in" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>